# re.sub for replacing block(multi line) of text in python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a block of text which is spanning over multiple lines of text file using python. Here is how my input file looks like.

input.txt:

```
ABCD abcd (
  . X (x),
   .Y (y)
);
ABCD1 abcd1 (
  . X1 (x1),
   .Y1 (y1)
);
```

I am reading the above file with the below code and trying to replace the text but failed to do so. Below is my code.

```
fo = open(input.txt, 'r')
input_str = fo.read()
find_str = '''ABCD abcd (
      .X (x),
      .Y (y)
     );'''

replace_str = '''ABCDE abcde (
      . XX (xx),
      .YY (yy)
      );'''

input_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, input_str)
```

But the input_str seems to be unchanged. Not sure what am I missing. Any clues?

Comment: If you replace literal strings why use regex? Use `input_str = input_str.replace(find_str, replace_str)`

Comment: The code contains indents in the strings but the sample data in your question is unindented. If this is correctly transcribed, the regex simply doesn't match.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: I've tried replace too. But unfortunately it didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using the re or regex modules? See [https://pypi.org/project/regex/](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)

Comment: Make sure you are replacing the exact same string, count all spaces, etc. It will work.

Comment: find_str in my script is obtained from regex match from input_str. So, I believe that's not an issue.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: You are right . replace worked. I did a blunder and expecting the code to work :D.

Comment: What does `'''` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe because parenthesis, ( and ) are meta characters of regular expressions.

Try by replacing `(` with `\(` and `)` with `\)`.

Or use replace method on string, for example,

```
input_str.replace(find_str, replace_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [ABCD\s+abcd\s+(\s+[.]\s*X\s*(x)\s*,\s*[.]Y\s*(y)\s*)\s*;](https://regex101.com/r/RgxyLE/1/)

```
ABCD
  \s+ #(1 or more 'spaces' (space, tab, new line...))
abcd
  \s+
\( # left parenthesis, you need to scape this because 
   # parenthesis mean 'capturin group' in a regexp
\s+
[.] # Dot means 'any single character but new line' on a regexp
    # so you need to scape it with either \. or [.]
\s*X\s* # (\s* means 0 or more spaces)
\(x\)
\s*,\s*
[.]Y\s*
\(y\)
\s*\)\s*;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub("([.]\\s*)(\\w+)(.*?)(\\w+)","\\1\\2\\2\\3\\4\\4",fo)

Out[412]: 'ABCD abcd (\n  . XX (xx),\n   .YY (yy)\n);\nABCD1 abcd1 (\n  . X1X1 (x1x1),\n   .Y1Y1 (y1y1)\n);'
```